# Корректное имя поля в MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql

у меня в таблице есть поле `meta_title` захотел переименовать его в стиле camelcase на имя `metaTitle` но почему то при вызове `echo $action['metaTitle']` ничего не происходит.

Для SQL запросов я использую ORM redBean php, для выборки я использую вот такой запрос:

```
$action = R::findOne(DB::MAIN.DB::TABLE_ACTIONS, 'section = ? AND url = ?', [$section['id'], $model]);
```

если распечатать запрос:

```
var_dump($action);
```

Я получаю вот такой объект:

```
object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)#19 (10) {
  ["properties":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["section"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["url"]=>
    string(4) "home"
    ["metaTitle"]=>
    string(31) "Главная страница"
  }
  ["__info":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(11) "mainactions"
    ["sys.id"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["sys.orig"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["section"]=>
      string(1) "1"
     ["url"]=>
      string(4) "home"
      ["metaTitle"]=>
      string(31) "Главная страница"
    }
    ["tainted"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["changed"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["changelist"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["model"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["beanHelper":protected]=>
  object(RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper)#11 (0) {
  }
  ["fetchType":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["withSql":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
 ["withParams":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["aliasName":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["via":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["noLoad":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["all":protected]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Я полагаю некорректное имя поля или неверные настройки сервера.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело!?

Comment: Как Вы данные берёте из базы? приведите код, пожалуйста.

Comment: дополнил вопрос.

Comment: вот [тут](https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/faq) последний заголовок и ниже - прочитайте. Судя по всему redbean действительно не разрешает использовать заглавные буквы в названиях полей.

Comment: Похоже что Вы правы, есть ли у Вас варианты обхода правил ORM?

Comment: к сожалению, мне не довелось иметь дело с RedBean. Попробуйте поменять теги в вопросе и переформулировать название и текст так, чтобы было понятно, что Вам нужна помощь именно с RedBean, а не с с MariaDB (сама база данных тут ни при чем, скорее всего).